# C# lock every object in collection before performing action

Tags: c#, locking, idisposable

I have a collection of objects:

```
List<SubscriptionSeat> seatsToRemove;
```

Each `SubscriptionSeat` object has a `GetModifyLock()` method to lock it in a distributed environment before making any changes to it.  Used as follows:

```
var seatToRemove = seatsToRemove[0];
using(seatToRemove.GetModifyLock())
{
    seatToRemove.HardDelete();
}
```

I want to perform an action on every object in `seatsToRemove` but I wish to obtain all their locks prior to performing the action.  Is a `try, finally` block statement the safest way of doing this to ensure all locks are disposed properly and that the action is only performed once all locks have been acquired?

```
var objLocks = new List<DistributedLock>();
try
{
    // Obtain locks
    foreach (var seatToRemove in seatsToRemove)
    {
        objLocks.Add(seatToRemove.GetModifyLock());
    }

    // Perform locked actions
    foreach (var seatToRemove in seatsToRemove)
    {
        seatToRemove.HardDelete();
    }
}
finally
{
    // Clean up
    foreach (var objLock in objLocks)
    {
        objLock.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think that you would have to lock the collection as well because right now there's nothing prohibiting two threads acquiring some of the locks of the objects in the collection in parallel, blocking each other from getting *all* locks.

Comment: do you HAVE to lock all elements of the list before you can perform the HardDelete on them? Doing this individually would be the better approach. Otherwise maybe create a SubscriptionSeatList that implements List<SubscriptionSeat> and has two methods LockElements and UnlockElements so you don't have to do it in your business code and implement it every time you're doing anything with these elements. I don't think that the try catch is necessary but if HardDelete can throw exceptions then you will have to LockElements, try{HardDelete}, finally{UnlockElements}

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can cause unhandled exceptions. To make it more reliable, you could create a disposable list and handle exception in there.

```
using (var objLocks = new DisposableList<DistributedLock>())
{
    // Obtain locks
    foreach (var seatToRemove in seatsToRemove)
    {
        objLocks.Add(seatToRemove.GetModifyLock());
    }

    // Perform locked actions
    foreach (var seatToRemove in seatsToRemove)
    {
        seatToRemove.HardDelete();
    }
}
```

**DisposableList**

```
public class DisposableList<T> : List<T>, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (T item in this)
        {
            try
            {
                IDisposable disposableItem = item as IDisposable;
                if (disposableItem != null)
                {
                    disposableItem.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ///Log and do something
            }
        }
        this.Clear();
        this.TrimExcess();
    }
}
```